# SQL Server setup with PDO on Redhat

Tags: php, sql-server

I am currently creating a PHP script to copy some data onto a Microsoft SQL server from a MySQL server. I decided to use PHP with PDO since I thought it would be a really quick process (famous last words).

The Mysql side is completed but I am completely stuck on the MS SQL side on how to get everything installed correctly. My work script server has several different drivers installed (freeTDS, Microsoft ODBC Drivers) and I am not sure how to setup this new MS SQL server in PHP especially to use PDO instead of the direct ODBC functions PHP has.

The work server uses PHP 5.3 which has caused problems with perl rejecting to install sqlsrv/pdo_sqlsrv since the server doesn't run PHP 7.1 or greater.

My main questions being:

1. Which driver should I use to setup the PHP 5.3 MSsql driver on a redhat server that will work with PDO?
2. What should my PDO connection string look like?

This is what I have now:

`$connectString = "sqlsrv:server=$host;Database=$schema;charset=$charset";`

3. Is it really necessary to define the server connection in the ODBC driver before hand?

Sorry I don't have more research into this it seems there are many ways to bring in MSsql in PHP and I'm not sure which path to go down for my specific version of PHP!

Answer (score 0):

I use this for MSSQL connection with pdo

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:SERVER=$dbhost;DATABASE=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpassword);
```

Comment: What components needed to be installed (assuming RHEL) to support the sqlsrv connection in PHP / PDO? Or is it stated to work out of the box?